# Ethereum wallet 0.9.0 slow sync (deleting block chain works but problem eventually comes back)

Tags: synchronization

Windows 8.1 with 8GB RAM, 400GB spare, i7 CPU. 100Mb fibre broadband. Bitcoin and Litecoin wallet syncs no problems.

So had an issue a few weeks back where block around 4 million was syncing at a rate of 2 blocks per second. Uninstalled client, deleted block chain data, reinstalled and allowed fast sync to kick in. Fast sync no problems. Launched client every day and allowed sync to happen. No issues. Now a few days later it's doing the same thing as before.

This seems to be a recurring issue that creeps in after the client has not been opened for a few days. Back to 2 blocks a second. I'm having to wait an 1hr 20 mins for syncing about 3 days worth of blockchain data. Any ideas?